# FactoryGirl doesn't save objects in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have code like that in spec/requests:

```
      describe "with valid data" do
        let(:player) { FactoryGirl.create :player }
        let(:player2) { FactoryGirl.create :player2 } 

        @player = Player.new(firstname: "Tom", lastname: "Greg", nickname: "jimi21")
        @player.save

        @players = Player.all
        p @players.count
      end
```

Output in console is:

> 1

Why this code don't create object in test DB? I mean this line:

```
let(:player) { FactoryGirl.create :player }
```

I want write some more tests based on players saved in DB.
How can I do it smartly using RSpec and FactoryGirl?

Code from FactoryGirl file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player do
    firstname "John"
    lastname "Smith"
    nickname "smithy99"
    avatar { File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/images/1.png')) }
  end

  factory :player2 do
    firstname "Tom"
    lastname "Marlow"
    nickname "marlowy11"
    avatar { File.new(Rails.root.join('spec/images/1.png')) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have any tests in your code there, and you're never referencing the variables you're setting in them, so your `let` blocks are never being run.

Tests in RSpec are wrapped in `it` blocks, eg.

```
it "tests something" do
  # This is a test! player will be defined here!
end
```

If you set up a test like this, and reference `player` and `player2` inside it, they will be defined.

If you don't wish to manually reference them for them to be defined, you may want to *eager load* them, using `let!` instead of `let`.

For a complete snippet of code that will do what I think you want:

```
  describe "with valid data" do
    let!(:player) { FactoryGirl.create :player }
    let!(:player2) { FactoryGirl.create :player2 } 

    it "doesn't allow duplicate names" do
      @player = Player.new(firstname: "Tom", lastname: "Greg", nickname: "jimi21")
      @player.save

      @players = Player.all
      p @players.count
    end
  end
```

Comment: Or you can just use local variables within the `it` block and ignore `let` entirely.

Comment: that too. But you still need the `it` block to have an actual test :)